# Get parent menu item object in plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, custom-field

**Problem**

Working with a code variation from this [tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin) I'm trying to get the parent menu item instance object of a given item (currently editing) and it always returns null.

```
/**
 * Prepare form and add my field.
 *
 * @param   JForm  $form  The form to be altered.
 * @param   mixed  $data  The associated data for the form.
 *
 * @return  boolean
 *
 * @since   0.0.1
 */
function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
{
    $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu   = $app->getMenu();
    $pid    = $data->parent_id;
    $parent = $menu->getItem($pid);
    $items  = $menu->getItems('menutype', $data->menutype);

    var_dump($data->parent_id); 
    // returns the parent_id string of the currently edited menu item

    var_dump($parent); 
    // returns null

    var_dump($items); 
    // returns null as well
}
```

**Questions:**

- Should I change the order of the plugins so mine executes last or hopefully after everything is initialized?
- Should I use a different callback other than `onContentPrepareForm`?
- Should I include/require anything from Joomla? If so, what is it?

Comment: Your last question isn't very clear. Can you elaborate or give some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are editing from administrator section, `$app->getMenu()` returns administrator menu items. Pass client argument if you need site items:

```
$menu = $app->getMenu('site');
```

> Should I change the order of the plugins so mine executes last or
>   hopefully after everything is initialized?

Probably not. Just note that plugin order does decide the order in which the form is altered. E.g. you might need to tweak the order in case you have multiple plugins modifying the same field. Or if you have dependencies on other plugins.

> Should I use a different callback other than onContentPrepareForm?

No, if you want to modify a form, this is the event to use. But at the very least you should check that you are modifying the correct form (or multiple forms).

```
public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
{
    // Check that we are editing a menu item.
    if ($form->getName() !== 'com_menus.item')
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Do our stuff.
}
```

Comment: The `$app->getMenu('site');` solved. Also thanks a million for the tips.